# Drupal Commerce: Calculating a shipping rate: Custom Shipping Price

Tags: commerce

I have a variety of products that have different fixed shipping prices. Each product has a custom field associated with it that contains a decimal price for shipping. Using Flat Rate Shipping, on the event "Calculating a shipping rate", how may I go about bringing in the custom field (scoping) to calculate that shipping price?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to have multiple flat rates, and a conditional rule that the product for that price is in the cart.

**Notes**:

- There's a commerce shipping rules module that has a "cart contains item" condition.
- If you could get at the logic behind the prices you could deal with this more easily, like weight based or size based shipping. For hundreds of products it's unreasonable that there's no logic behind it outside of what they want to charge for shipping. What I could think of is a custom module using hook_commerce shipping method alter where the shipping method matched the shipping price in the field. I've written a small module that alters the shipping weight, but that again assumes logic the weight based shipping.

Comment: Not a bad workaround--I'll give it a shot.

Comment: There's a commerce shipping rules module that has a "cart contains item" condition, I'd have posted more details but I'm posting in transit from my phone

Comment: If I added that type of rule, I'd have to do it for hundreds of products, and it would be tough for the client to change. It would be radically better to simply take a field from the product instead.

Comment: Just out curiosity, how are the shipping rates so different from product to product? What are the shipping rates based on?

Comment: I'm not actually sure. The client is shipping training materials, and is arbitrarily choosing shipping prices.

Comment: So, if you could get at the logic behind the prices you could deal with this more easily, like weight based or size based shipping. For hundreds of products it's unreasonable that there's no logic behind it outside of what they want to charge for shipping. What I could think of is a custom module using hook_commerce shipping method alter where the shipping method matched the shipping price in the field. I've written a small module that alters the shipping weight, but that again assumes logic the weight based shipping

Comment: I think we're just going to end up adding the shipping price to the overall price and say "shipping included" :)

Comment: that's one way to do it. :p

Comment: @nizz0k : please check my edited version of your answer (I only integrated some of your comments in it). If needed further enhance it, or if you don't like my edit at all just perform a rollback to the prior version, ok? PS: are you still "in transit"?

Comment: Hi Pierre, nope, thankfully I arrive at my destination a long time ago : ) In respect to your edits, I don't see any issue with them, good job.